# Java Do While loop that keeps repeating the same output

Tags: do-while

Im trying to write this code to read the value inputed, and then output the sum of the even integers between 2 and the input. It does it correctly, but i can't get the code to stop repeating the same output. How can i get it to output it once, and stop repeating it?

```
 Scanner calculator = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a number greater than 2:");
            int num = calculator.nextInt();
            do {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 2; i <= num; i += 2) {
                    sum += i;
                }
                System.out.println("The sum of the even numbers through " + num + " is "+ sum);
            }while (num >= 2 );
        
        
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Tip: run the program yourself using a pencil and paper.

Comment: Also, I don't think you should name your `Scanner` instance as `calculator` because **it isn't a calculator**, it's a text-reader. Just name it `scanner` (all-lowercase) otherwise your program is confusing to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creation and storage of the value stored in num, and all further requests from standard input exist outside the do while loop. Consider adding in the while loop a request to standard input: `num = calculator.nextInt();`.